# how to add an overlay using jQuery +css?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show a container with overlay (mean black theme display on background) which displays slowly and displays in full after few seconds. So I used opacity property in that but it is not working for me.

I want to show the container slowly with black overlay using css.
here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g7Jj2/

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    opacity: 0;    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
}
.cc{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g7Jj2/1/

Your CSS is being overridden due to specificity.
Use this instead:

```
#container.cc{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: why you use #container.cc

Comment: to add specificity . id has more specificity  than class.

Comment: if i don't want any space between the field .and overlay see over the field

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.cc{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/g7Jj2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
  #container{
width:100%;
background:red;
height:100px;
opacity: 0;    
transition: opacity 2s ease;
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
 #container.cc{
opacity: 1;
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Jj2/4/)

Comment: why it is taking space 100 px in between the fields